# Css Background how this site did it?

Tags: html, css, background

I cannot find where the grainy-ish grey background is coming from on this website..

the image is a simple png with only white lines. There ARE grainy overlay on the background right?

what css am I missing here?

http://www.precipart.com/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.grey_texture_bg {
  background: url(/assets/textured_grey.png) top left repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The background is coming from the class`grey_texture_bg` on the `<section>` element

Here is a good resource for such background patterns: [subtlepatterns.com](http://subtlepatterns.com/)